# How can I get scala to work in the command line?

Tags: scala

I run Windows 7.

I have java (a current enough version to run scala) and scala downloaded on my computer.  I've set PATH so that when I type "scala" into the command prompt it sends me to the proper interface:

Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information

However I can't execute the command "scala" or "scalac" on my test files.

```
scala> scala Hello
(console):8: error: object Hello is not a member of package scala
```

This makes me think I'm in the wrong directory.  The file Hello.scala is saved in the home directory that I set PATH to.

However I get a different issue when I try to compile code.

```
scala> scalac Hello.scala
(console):1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
```

I actually got my test file to work at one point... but I wasn't actually IN scala.

```
C:\scala-2.9.1.final\bin> scala Hello.scala
Hello world!
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here.  If anyone has any ideas of what may be wrong I would greatly appreciate input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to run & compile programs from within the Scala *REPL* (read-evaluate-print loop - a kind of Scala interpreter) and you cannot do that in the REPL. The REPL allows you to type in Scala statements and see them execute immediately. (If you're not sure how you entered the REPL, you probably just entered the command `scala` from the command line.) The REPL is useful for testing ideas, and for experimenting with Scala. For example:

```
C:\some\path> scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> println ("Hello!")
Hello!

scala> val x = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> val y = x * 5
y: Int = 50

scala> sys.exit
C:\some\path>
```

However, the REPL isn't what you would use to compile & run Scala programs - you need to do that from the command line (or from a tool such as *[sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)*). If you want to run your program directly from the command line, without using the REPL (that is, without being *in Scala*, as you put it) then you would need to do the following:

Firstly, compile your program using **scalac**:

`C:\some\path> scalac Hello.scala`

If that succeeds, you can then run the program with the **scala** command (which looks for a Hello.class file):

`C:\some\path> scala Hello`

(Here `C:\some\path` is the location of the files `Hello.scala` & `Hello.class`.)

Alternatively, as you have already discovered, you can run your Scala program as a script in the REPL. You can do this from the command line as follows (note the addition of the filetype `.scala` after `Hello` compared to the command above):

`C:\some\path> scala Hello.scala`

or from within the REPL:

`scala> :load Hello.scala`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to issue `scala` command when you're inside REPL. If you want to execute code from that file, load it:

here is what I have in Foo.scala

```
println("I'm foo")
```

Now I'm starting the REPL (and as you can see `scala>` is a sign that you're ALREADY into REPL and can start execute raw scala code):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :load Foo.scala
Loading Foo.scala...
I'm foo
```

Comment: I also tried using it on my file but didn't work, said the file doesn't exist.  Maybe I'm in the wrong directory?

Comment: To get help on the load command, type `:help load` rather than `:help :load` (the colon is the prefix for a command, to distinguish it from a Scala statement).